# Making large REST requests

Tags: android, rest

I have a REST service I can't alter, with methods for uploading an image, encoded as a Base64 string.

The problem is that the images can go up to sizes of 5-10MB, perhaps more. When I try to construct a Base64 representation of an image of this size on the device, I get an OutOfMemory exception.

I can however encode chunks of bytes at a time (3000 let's say), but this is useless as I would need the whole string to create a HttpGet/HttpPost object:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("www.server.com/longString");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
```

Is there a way of going around this?

Edit: trying to use Heiko Rupp's suggestions + the android doc, I get an exception ("java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.google.com") at the following line: InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write("/translate".getBytes());

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }           
        System.out.println("response:" + total);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Am I missing something? The GET request that I need to execute looks like this: 
"*http://myRESTService.com/myMethod?params=LOOONG-String*", so the idea was to connect to *http://myRESTService.com/myMethod* and then output a few characters of the long string at a time. Is this correct?

Comment: you need to tell the service to use put or post e.g. via con.setMethod("POST")

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the `URLConnection` instead of the apache http client, as this does not require you to hold the object to send in memory, but instead you can do something like:

**pseudocode!**

```
HttpUrlConnection con = restUrl.getConnection();
while (!done) {
  byte[] part = base64encode(partOfImage);
  con.write (part);
  partOfImage = nextPartOfImage();
}
con.flush();
con.close();
```

Also in Android after 2.2 Google recommends the `URLConnection` over the http client. See the description of [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html).

The other thing you may want to look into is the amount of data to be sent. 10 MB + base64 will take quite a while to transfer (even with gzip compression, which the `URLConnection` transparently enables if the server side accepts it) over a mobile network.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I'm having trouble however with using that method.. I have no way of knowing that the request goes through without looking at the response. How would I do that? could you please check the edited part of my question?

Answer (score 1):

You must read docs for this REST service, no such service will require you to send such long data in GET. Images are always sent as POST. POST data is always at the end of request and allows to be added iteratively.

Comment: There are no docs for this service. Even if there were, we would probably not have access to them. This REST service afaik is a newly-added wrapper for an old SOAP service.. which again, is POORLY documented.

Comment: have you checked if this server will accept such long URL? Most servers will accept at most few KB length urls.